# Managing duplicated rows in large data frames

Tags: r, memory-management, plyr

I would like to tag samples (`sample_id` collumn) with more than one `State` in the same `no` collumn with `E` string.

My `df` dataframe input:

```
          no               sample_id  State 
chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001788    0n
chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001788    1n
chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001836    0n
chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE002026    0n
chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001413    0n
chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001438    0n
```

My expected `output`:

```
          no               sample_id  State 
chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001788    E
chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001836    0n
chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE002026    0n
chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001413    0n
chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001438    0n
```

The sample `NE001788` was tagged with E because it have two different states (`State`) in a same `no` string.
I had used the below code to small dataframes:

```
df <- read.table(text= 'no  sample_id  State 
                 chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001788    0n
                 chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001788    1n
                 chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001836    0n
                 chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE002026    0n
                 chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001413    0n
                 chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001438    0n',header=TRUE) 

library(plyr)
output <- unique(ddply(df,.(no,sample_id),mutate,State=if(length(unique(State))>1) {"E"} else State))
```

It works fine. However, I have now a large data frame (more than 700k rows). In this large dataframe I get a memory error: `cannot allocate vector of size 75kb`.

I am here to ask alternatives to reach the same result, without memory breakout.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In your expected output you deleted the duplicated row, was that on purpose or by mistake? Because you didn't specfy that in your request

Comment: Yes, I wanna to delete the duplicated rows and create just one with "E" `State`. In my output I don´t wanna two `no` entries to a same `sample_id`. When I get more than one entry I would like to create the "E" row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `data.table`. I didn't benchmark this code, but it should be certainly better than `plyr`

```
library(data.table)
df <- setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(.N > 1, "E", as.character(x))), by = c("no", "sample_id"), .SDcols = "State"]

##                           no sample_id State
## 1: chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001788     E
## 2: chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001836    0n
## 3: chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE002026    0n
## 4: chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001413    0n
## 5: chr1-15984544-15996851-0n  NE001438    0n
```

Better option will be to first make `State` a character (if it's not already) in order to avoid doing `as.character` in each group, and then do the subsetting. Something like

```
setDT(df)[, State := as.character(State)]
df <- df[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(.N > 1, "E", x)), by = c("no", "sample_id"), .SDcols = "State"]
```

Answer (score 1):

And here's the `dyplr` code to do it:

```
dd %>%
  mutate(State = as.character(State)) %>%
  group_by(no, sample_id) %>%
  summarize(State = ifelse(length(unique(State)) > 1, "E", State))
```

Most likely, using `dplyr` will be faster than `plyr`, but I don't know how it compares in terms of memory usage, since that seems to be the bottleneck in your case.

Note that I convert `State` to character before the operation because if you read in the data from the question, it will be `factor`s. If in reality they are characters, you can skip that of course.

Note: I use `length(unique(State)) > 1` to cover the (hypothetical) case where entries in `no`, `sample_id` and `State` are all the same in multiple rows. Based on your description you wouldn't want to assign `E` to `State` in that case, but it's not clear if such a case is possible at all in your data. If not, you could replace `length(unique(State)) > 1` with `n() > 1`.